# Cocoa fullscreen on secondary display without blanking main display mac

Tags: cocoa, fullscreen

Is there any way to get a fullscreen window on a secondary display without blanking the first? 
Quicktime does this when you drag a window and then press command-F

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-[NSView enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:]`.

Alternatively, you can create or configure a borderless window whose content rect coincides with the frame of the desired `NSScreen` and set its window level to `NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1`.

Both of these predate Lion's full-screen feature and so work differently.